# Scrapy: a simple way to get around a tiny javascript function?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

**EDIT:** I've asked a very-related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978818/using-initspider-with-splash-only-parsing-the-login-page).

I'm scraping data from a website using Scrapy which seemed like it was pretty straightforward, except that the page I eventually wanted came back looking like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function get_tz()
    {
      var now = new Date()
      document.tz_form.offset.value = now.getTimezoneOffset()
      document.tz_form.submit()
    }
  </script>
  <object><noscript>
    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Javascript support is needed for this page (to get your local timezone).<br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  Your browser either has no Javascript support,
 or has such support disabled.<br />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  As an alternative, click <a href="http://www.bridgebase.com/myhands/hands.php?offset=0">here</a> to continue.<br />
  All times will be GMT.</p>  </noscript></object>
</head>
  <body onload='get_tz()'>
   <form name="tz_form" action="/myhands/hands.php?traveller=5043-1453474920-72755316" method="post">
      <input type='hidden' name='offset' />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm pretty new to web scraping and I've read some stuff about how to get around this using splash or selenium, but I wanted to ask if there was an easy way to get around this before diving deeper. All I need to do is supply this bit of time zone information. I'm not sure if it's as easy as it looks...

My spider is a little verbose because of authentication, but I can supply that if people think it helps. I figured it wouldn't be too critical here.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do.. If you're looking to submit the form on that page, it should not be too hard though. Essentially, you need to emulate what the script is doing in your Python code, ie. Get the user's timezone in your code, and submit that to the URL action of the form as a plain HTTP post.  Unfortunately, I don't know Python, so I can't really tell you specifically how to do this.