# Passing cookies to subsequent requests in CrawlSpider

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a bridge website for some results from recent tournaments. I've posted a previous question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978818/using-initspider-with-splash-only-parsing-the-login-page/35372405#35372405). Thanks to @alecxe, I've gotten the scraper to log in while rendering some JavaScript on the page using `PhantomJS`.

How I understand this works is that I log in using `selenium`, save the credentials in a cookie, and then pass the cookie to an ordinary `CrawlSpider` to get the authentication done, thereby bypassing issues with `InitSpider`. This works fine for the initial login page, but once the crawler goes to the next page defined by the `Rule`, the website kicks me out. It just scrapes the login page again.

To fix this, I tried saving the cookie in a global variable and overriding `make_requests_from_url()` to pass the cookie to all subsequent requests the spider makes. But it still returns the body of the login page.

**Question:** what is going on here? I heard from somewhere that once you pass the cookie to `start_requests()` then the cookie is supposed to persist for the rest of the `CrawlSpider` session. But it clearly doesn't do that. Can anyone enlighten me as to where I can see how Scrapy handles this?

My code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request, HtmlResponse

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class BboSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
    name = "bbo"
    allowed_domains = ["bridgebase.com"]
    login_page = "http://www.bridgebase.com/myhands/myhands_login.php?t=%2Fmyhands%2Findex.php%3F" 

    def start_requests(self):
        global bbo_cookies

        driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        driver.get(self.login_page)    
        driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("_____")
        driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("_____")
        driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
        driver.save_screenshot("test.png")
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Click here for results of recent tournaments")))

        bbo_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
        driver.close()

        yield Request("http://webutil.bridgebase.com/v2/tarchive.php?m=h&h=acbl&d=ACBL&o=acbh", cookies=bbo_cookies)

    def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
        request = super(BboSpider, self).make_requests_from_url(url)
        request.cookies = bbo_cookies
        return request

    rules = [ 
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'tourney=4796-1455303720-'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
            ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print(response.body)
```

The barebones relevant portion of the log (for now) reveals nothing too interesting. I can provide more details if necessary.

```
2016-02-13 09:31:04 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-02-13 09:31:04 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-02-13 09:31:04 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

[... bunch of Selenium messages ...]

2016-02-13 09:31:13 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://webutil.bridgebase.com/v2/tarchive.php?m=h&h=acbl&d=ACBL&o=acbh> (referer: None)

[... more Selenium messages ...]

2016-02-13 09:31:16 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.bridgebase.com/myhands/hands.php?tourney=4796-1455303720-> (referer: http://webutil.bridgebase.com/v2/tarchive.php?m=h&h=acbl&d=ACBL&o=acbh)
2016-02-13 09:31:17 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-02-13 09:31:17 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

Clearly, I am not understanding something about how scrapy works.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your regex isnt correct... you're limitin the the search to just that one...

```
rules = [ 
'''
...allow=r'tourney=4796-1455303720-' 
'''
]
```

## '#TO DO:  Fix your regex...

***Its literally just being allowed to serach that specific id for tourney ..., also you should include the slashe in your link rules...***

## REGEX AS YOU HAVE IT...

```
"allow=r'tourney-id=123'
tourney-id=123 ... FOUND IT! MATCHES THE ASLLOW RULE;
tourney-id=456 ...- NOPE, NOT ALLOWED
tourney-id=789... NOPE! BOT ALLOWED... YOU DONT LET DO NUFIN!
```

So you see what you did there?

Though I have no reproduced your script looks very clean to me... aside from that regex deal, such well made logic but the regex is lacking? lol Im sure it was just a oversight so I wont question your skill... Such written well writen code, I HAVE to beleive you know your reg.

If you do need help with that let me know I guess,

*-Scriptso*

PS  Im really just getting serious about finally diving in tothis comunity, couple neg votes past 3 years.  if you find that I was any help give me an upvote yeh?! lol

## EDIT !

So out of curiosity I'm running your script and it is not as clean as I thought it was reading it at first seem logical (eith obvious mistakes I read over myself) but there's a bunch of errors as far as the trace back the error log led me to initially believe that it was a pretty clean execution but the truth is it's all out of whack... first...

```
class BboSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
```

Whe you define your spider class its either one or the other... scrapy.spider, or CrawlSpider, or a custome build but either way being a derivative one.... or the other lol
*depending what you choose...*
Using crawl spider you end up having to defin your items in the items.py...  you did not call for items just running a print??
Crawlerers... though theres not a real need other then doing things right to itemize in item by, if your going to use crawler then you gota
define the item class

```
YourItems(item):
item1 = Field()
etc etc...
```

May I suggest every time you do start a scrapy project you use (which you might already) use scrapy startproject arg.  I now really made a 180 and assume you copied and paste most of this??? Actually It kinda looks like you smashed 2-3 together LMAO, its all right !  We all start somewhere but learning the hard way is well... in efficient...

For what you trying to do, you dont have to incorporate selenium... ALREADY a whole different beast, instead take onn the smaller runts before you level up your python skills (There is a coralation between the scrapys logic framework  + module use and the level of understanding of how python works.. im not pro but im way past noob)

What should you probly use?
Id recomend simply request module with ForumRequest option... simple login an there you go...

Using Selenium is cool and all but the need to carry cookies is realistically its having to get the hang of selenium which is a dawting task being that its a prety heavy module and though you should by all means learn it if you want....  You dont have to kill yourself... SOO!...

Ill be here if you need help, just message me, half the satisfaction of learning the bits and peices (also the life sucking, social-stigmatic part of all it... im such a fn nerd #facepalm) thats learning the new stuff but take it step at a time and if general rule of thumb... If your guna use a library, module, extension for any language... know the ins and outs of it before tackling on complex stuff....

Comment: Looks good! Would recommend a bit of grammatical editing, but welcome to Stackoverflow, enjoy your stay :D

Comment: @penne12 LMAO! thanks? its only been 2+ years  to appreciate SO, I work on my english

Comment: @penne12 I dont see any refrence to stack overflow and having google translate tag block to pass through a post.... would be awesome, probably make me not look iliterate